# how to access promoise variable value outside

Tags: promise, scope, protractor

```
async selectAvailableRoute(routeCount: number) : Promise<any>{
var newRouteNum='';
for (let i = 1; i <= routeCount; i++) {

  this.availableRoute(i).click();
  this.availableRoute(i).getText().then(function (createdRouteNum) {
    Utils.logger('number'+ createdRouteNum);
    newRouteNum= createdRouteNum;

   });
return newRouteNum;

}
```

}

value of newRouteNum is coming as undefined. Can someone help to get the proper value

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about taking a value outside of a Promise as you could be executing that outside code before the Promise gets resolved: see the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/2750819) but in short, get used to the asynchronous nature of Javascript. Instead just pass the Promise itself around and continue to use the resolved value.

```
async selectAvailableRoute(routeCount: number) : Promise<any>{
  // do whatever
  return this.availableRoute(i).getText().then(function (createdRouteNum) {
    // do whatever
    return createdRouteNum;
  });
}

// Just keep reusing the Promise as follows
var promise = selectAvailableRoute(...)
promise.then(function(createdRouteNum) {
   // do whatever
});
```

You can use the async/await syntax to alleviate the nesting but it doesn't change the nature of the problem.